# Thinkpad T420s Intel HD 3000 poor performance

Tags: crunchbang, opengl, intel-graphics

just installed crunchbang, and find it a bit laggy so checked glxinfo and it seems that i have no OpenGL-Support:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: 
Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:`
```

could somebody please help me out, I googled but just don't get it, and don't know whats causing the Problem, or how to fix it...

```
sudo lshw -C video
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

Comment: Just referencing your forum post: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=384025

Comment: Try the fixes here: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_HD_Graphics

Comment: I can't see anything related to my problem in the link you posted...don't have hybrid graphics and Power Saving Kernel Options seems "Off Topic" for me...

Comment: Do you have any BIOS settings related as described in that link?

Comment: Please confirm if you're using the i915 drivers: `sudo lshw -C video`.

Comment: Potentially related: http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers

Comment: yes driver is i915, I will update my question with the full output

Comment: do you know if the ppa is also supported for debian/crunchbang?

Comment: Sorry no, I don't know. I might be inclined to try it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this Question [how to test if my video card hast 3d-support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31488/how-to-test-if-my-video-card-has-3d-support)
If I understand the answer correctly, the

```
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
```

doesn't say anything about the 3D-Support, the important line is

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset
```

so it seems that everything is set up right for OpenGL in my case.

I've just updated Iceweasel and Flash-Player and it seems that it's not as laggy as before, still my CPU goes up to 50% watching a 1080p Video... :-/

Comment: Using Flash to view video is a recipe for pain and disappointment.  Consider installing `mplayer2`, `vlc`, or `ffmpeg/ffplay` to view videos instead.